# Filter list according to non-existence of substrings from another list

Tags: google-apps-script

I tried using `includes` to make the filter, but even though there is an equivalent substring in the list, it was not removed, what is the most correct method to achieve the result I want?

```javascript
function new_eps(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('series');
  var new_optts = [['CSI: Vegas\nS2E16 - LEG§§§ccc§§§ddd'],['The Ark\nS1E06 - LEG§§§aaa§§§bbb']];
  var col_g = ss.getRange('G1:G').getValues();
  var col_g_flat = col_g.flat(); // ['CSI: Vegas\nS2E16 - LEG§§§eee§§§fff','The Last of Us\nS1E09 - DUB§§§ggg§§§hhh'];
  var not_match = new_optts.filter(x => !col_g_flat.includes(x[0].substring(0, x[0].indexOf('§§§'))));
  console.log(not_match);
}
```

Actual result:

```
[ [ 'CSI: Vegas\nS2E16 - LEG§§§ccc§§§ddd' ],
  [ 'The Ark\nS1E06 - LEG§§§aaa§§§bbb' ] ]
```

Expected result (because `CSI: Vegas\nS2E16 - LEG` is found as substring):

```
[ [ 'The Ark\nS1E06 - LEG§§§aaa§§§bbb' ] ]
```

Comment: I want to understand something, you are comparing the values `CSI: Vegas\nS2E16 - LEG§§§ccc§§§ddd` and `CSI: Vegas\nS2E16 - LEG§§§eee§§§fff`. However, you want to compare only this part ``CSI: Vegas\nS2E16 - LEG`?

Comment: Hi @GiselleValladares only ```CSI: Vegas\nS2E16 - LEG``` and ```The Last of Us\nS1E09 - DUB```

Comment: @DigitalFarmer curious to know if Giselle's answer was the solution you were looking for? (having a kind of similar issue over here)

Comment: Hello @YancyGodoy , I haven't had the opportunity to do the tests yet, but visually if your spreadsheet string is as it indicated, yes. It will solve the case, however for mine, I believe it will not have the exact return because the spreadsheet string has a real line break and the string has more characters than what it defined as a general value (note that the complete value has additional ones starting with ```§§§```, example: ```CSI:Vegas\nS2E16 - LEG§§§eee§§§fff```). But anyway, as soon as I analyze it, I'll tag you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are currently having is that the Apps Script is taking the `\n` as the newline character instead of an actual character. This is why the name doesn't match with the one in the Google Sheet. You can read a little about this [here](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial/javascript-new-line#:%7E:text=The%20newline%20character%20is%20%5Cn,new%20line%20to%20a%20string).

In order to solve this problem, you only need to replace the `\n` with the character entity equivalent to `\n`. In this case `\\n` is used as  `replace` text in Google Sheets using regex.

If the Google sheet data is set like this:

[image: Google sheet data]

You can use this sample code:

```
function new_eps(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('series');
  var new_optts = [['CSI: Vegas\nS2E16 - LEG§§§ccc§§§ddd'],['The Ark\nS1E06 - LEG§§§aaa§§§bbb']];
  var col_g = ss.getRange('G1:G').getValues();
  var col_g_flat = col_g.flat(); // ['CSI: Vegas\nS2E16 - LEG§§§eee§§§fff','The Last of Us\nS1E09 - DUB§§§ggg§§§hhh'];
  var not_match = new_optts.filter(x =>  !col_g_flat.includes( x[0].substring(0, x[0].indexOf('§§§')).replace(/\n/gm, "\\n")));
  console.log(not_match);
}
```

And you should get:

[image: Execution log]

**Reference:**

- [Add a New Line in JavaScript](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial/javascript-new-line#:%7E:text=The%20newline%20character%20is%20%5Cn,new%20line%20to%20a%20string)
- [Find and replace text in Google Sheets using TextFinder and Apps Script](https://spreadsheet.dev/find-and-replace-google-sheets-textfinder-apps-script)